# Rendering Mapbox Vector Tiles using maplibre-gl-js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I'm trying to render Mapbox Vector Tiles using maplibre-gl-js library with the following code:

```
this.map = new maplibregl.Map({
  container: this.element,
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10'
})
```

It works, but all Mapbox requests are listed in Mapbox's statistics as 'Map Loads for Web'.

Is there any way to use Mapbox vector tiles with maplibre using only the Mapbox Vector Tiles API?

Comment: Good question - very hard to answer with certainty. I'd suggest contacting Mapbox directly and reporting back.